# Meteor 1.3 - Group elements in div's 3 at a time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm using Meteor 1.3 and I am trying to create a template where I load documents from a collection, and create a div for each of them. I want them to be grouped in lines of three because I am using bootstrap's `row` class.

I tried opening a div every time the index is modulo 3, then putting the content, then closing the div. However, Meteor can't have unclosed tags inside `{{#if}}`. What is the workaround to achieve what I want? My code shows the logic I want to apply (and apparently it would work before Meteor 0.8.0).

```
<template name="OrganizationsTpl">

    <div class="row">

    {{#each organizations}}

        {{#if modulo3 @index}} <!-- modulo3 is a  helper I defined -->
            {{#if @index}}     <!-- If index !=0 -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        </div>

    {{/each}}

    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could presumably split your organizations list into an `organizationsArray[][]` (or an object) where the right side of the array contains three organizations.

```
[0][organization0, organization1, organization2]
[1][anotherorganization, andanother, yetanother]
```

And do something like this

```
{{#each organizationsArray}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each organizations}}
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h1>{{name}}</h1>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

This isn't a working solution, but you get the picture

Comment: This is great, now I only have to find a way to split my cursor into arrays :P

Comment: @Savvas - If you're reading organizations from a Mongo collection, you can use `fetch()` to load them into an array (and then split that array into batches yourself): `myArray = MyCollection.find({ ... }).fetch()`

Answer (score 2):

If you directly insert the HTML code between your spacebar then I will give you an error.

So Here you can define a helper which return the '`</div><div class="row">`' as a string. Then inside your template, you can render it as HTML using {{{}}}.

```
<template name="OrganizationsTpl">
    <div class="row">
      {{#each organizations}}
          {{#if modulo3 @index}} <!-- modulo3 is a  helper I defined -->
              {{#if @index}} <!-- If index !=0 -->
                 {{{divBreak}}}
              {{/if}}     
         {{/if}} 
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

Your helper code will look like:

```
Template.OrganizationsTpl.helpers({
     'divBreak': function() {
         return '</div><div class="row">';
     }
});
```

Comment: The app runs now, and the appearance is ok, but firebug shows this structure, which seems weird.

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-4">
</div>

Comment: From the [documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Triple-braced-Tags): *The inserted HTML must consist of balanced HTML tags. You can’t, for example, insert `"</div><div>"` to close an existing div and open a new one.*